# Change label name in ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I have attached My Data below.

I wish to relabel "Cumulative number of events", which seem to be the default text. I would like it to read: "Cumulative number of recurrences". I can't seem to figure out how to change it - is it even possible to change the text?

My graph looks like this:

[image]

The graph was computed with this

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggplot2)
fit <- survfit(Surv(p$time.recur.months, p$recurrence) ~ p$simpson.grade, conf.type="log", data=p)


j <- ggsurvplot(
fit,                     
data = p, 
fun="cumhaz",
risk.table = TRUE,       
pval = TRUE,      
pval.coord = c(0, 0.25),
conf.int = F,         
legend.labs=c("Simpson Grade 1" ,"Simpson Grade 2", "Simpson Grade 3", 
"Simpson Grade 4"),
 size=c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7),                    
 xlim = c(0,100),
 alpha=c(0.7),
 break.time.by = 10,    
 xlab="Time in months",
 #ylab="Survival probability",
 ggtheme = theme_gray(),             
 risk.table.y.text.col = T,
 risk.table.y.text = TRUE,           
 ylim=c(0,0.5),
cumevents=T,
 palette="Set1"       
)

My Data
p <- structure(list(recurrence = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), time.recur.months = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 92L, NA, NA, NA, 74L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 8L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 58L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 39L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12L, 56L, 57L, NA, NA, 49L, 17L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA, 
89L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 6L, 8L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 60L, NA, NA, 38L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 90L, 
NA, 58L, 54L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53L, NA, NA, 124L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, NA), simpson.grade = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("recurrence", 
"time.recur.months", "simpson.grade"), class = "data.frame", row.names 
= c(NA, 
-176L))
```

Comment: why does the hazard rate increase and what does it mean, then?

Comment: This is not a hazard rate but a cumulative hazard, which simply correspond to *1 - Kaplan Meier estimate* obtained by specifying the `fun = "cumhaz"` argument as demonstrated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change title for `cumevents` table you need to use argument `cumevents.title`.

```
ggsurvplot(fit, p, 
           fun = "cumhaz",
           risk.table = TRUE, cumevents = TRUE,
           pval = TRUE, pval.coord = c(0, 0.25), conf.int = FALSE,
           legend.labs = paste("Simpson Grade", 1:4),
           xlab = "Time in months",
           cumevents.title = "Cumulative number of recurrences",
           size = rep(0.7, 4),
           xlim = c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 0.5),
           alpha = 0.7,
           break.time.by = 10,
           ggtheme = theme_gray(),
           risk.table.y.text.col = TRUE,
           risk.table.y.text = TRUE,
           palette = "Set1")
```

[image]