# ggsurvplot can't get cumulative events table font size to change

Tags: r

I started with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342797/change-label-name-in-ggsurvplot) as a base for my ggsurvplot graph, and I'm using their reproducible code for my question as well.

My problem is I can't figure out how to change the font size for the cumulative event table. Based on [this documentation](http://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggsurvplot.html), it looks like I should be able to specify cumevents.fontsize = x, but no matter what value I put in for that, the font size does not change. I'm trying to set it to teh same size as the risk.table.fontsize, but you can see that they are different in the graph below.

[image]

The graph was computed with this

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggplot2)
fit <- survfit(Surv(p$time.recur.months, p$recurrence) ~ p$simpson.grade, conf.type="log", data=p)


ggsurvplot(
fit,                     
data = p, 
risk.table = TRUE, 
risk.table.fontsize = 2,
cumevents = TRUE,
cumevents.fontsize =2,   
pval = TRUE,      
pval.coord = c(0, 0.25),
conf.int = F,         
legend.labs=c("Simpson Grade 1" ,"Simpson Grade 2", "Simpson Grade 3", 
"Simpson Grade 4"),
 size=c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7),                    
 xlim = c(0,100),
 alpha=c(0.7),
 break.time.by = 10,    
 xlab="Time in months",
 #ylab="Survival probability",
 ggtheme = theme_gray(),             
 risk.table.y.text.col = T,
 risk.table.y.text = TRUE,           
 ylim=c(0,0.5),
 palette="Set1"       
)

My Data
p <- structure(list(recurrence = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), time.recur.months = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 92L, NA, NA, NA, 74L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 8L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 58L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 39L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12L, 56L, 57L, NA, NA, 49L, 17L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA, 
89L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 6L, 8L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 60L, NA, NA, 38L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 90L, 
NA, 58L, 54L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53L, NA, NA, 124L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, NA), simpson.grade = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("recurrence", 
"time.recur.months", "simpson.grade"), class = "data.frame", row.names 
= c(NA, 
-176L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see the documentation for a `cumevents.fontsize` argument, but a straightforward way to change it is to store the plot and change it directly:

```r
mygg <- ggsurvplot(
fit,                     
data = p, 
risk.table = TRUE, 
risk.table.fontsize = 2,
cumevents = TRUE,
cumevents.fontsize =2,   
pval = TRUE,      
pval.coord = c(0, 0.25),
conf.int = F,         
legend.labs=c("Simpson Grade 1" ,"Simpson Grade 2", "Simpson Grade 3", 
"Simpson Grade 4"),
 size=c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7),                    
 xlim = c(0,100),
 alpha=c(0.7),
 break.time.by = 10,    
 xlab="Time in months",
 #ylab="Survival probability",
 ggtheme = theme_gray(),             
 risk.table.y.text.col = T,
 risk.table.y.text = TRUE,           
 ylim=c(0,0.5),
 palette="Set1"       
)
```

So now you can do:

```
 mygg$cumevents$layers[[1]]$aes_params$size <- 2
 
 mygg
```

[image]

or

```r
 mygg$cumevents$layers[[1]]$aes_params$size <- 8
 
 mygg
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks !! Works great for cumcensors as well!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion how to get a clean table: See here https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/117

```
p1 <- ggsurvplot(
  fit,                     
  data = p, 
  risk.table = TRUE, 
  cumevents = TRUE,  
  
  risk.table.title = "No. at Risk",
  cumevents.title = "Cumulative No. of Events",
  risk.table.height = 0.15, cumevents.height = 0.15,
  risk.table.y.text = TRUE,
  cumevents.y.text = TRUE,
  pval = TRUE,
  pval.coord = c(0, 0.25),
  conf.int = F,
  legend.labs=c("Simpson Grade 1" ,"Simpson Grade 2", "Simpson Grade 3", "Simpson Grade 4"),
  size=c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7),
  xlim = c(0,100),
  alpha=c(0.7),
  break.time.by = 10,
  xlab="Time in months",
  ylab="Survival probability",
  ggtheme = theme_gray(),
  risk.table.y.text.col = T,
  # risk.table.y.text = TRUE,           
  ylim=c(0,0.5),
  palette="Set1"
)

p1$table <- p1$table + theme_cleantable()
p1$cumevents <- p1$cumevents + theme_cleantable()
p1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just add fontsize=2 in ggsurvplot, it will apply to both risk table and cumevent table:

```
ggsurvplot(
  fit,                     
  data = p, 
  risk.table = TRUE, 
  #risk.table.fontsize = 2,
  cumevents = TRUE,
  #cumevents.fontsize =2,  
  fontsize=2, 
  pval = TRUE,      
  pval.coord = c(0, 0.25),
  conf.int = F,         
  legend.labs=c("Simpson Grade 1" ,"Simpson Grade 2", "Simpson Grade 3", 
                "Simpson Grade 4"),
  size=c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7),                    
  xlim = c(0,100),
  alpha=c(0.7),
  break.time.by = 10,    
  xlab="Time in months",
  #ylab="Survival probability",
  ggtheme = theme_gray(),             
  risk.table.y.text.col = T,
  risk.table.y.text = TRUE,           
  ylim=c(0,0.5),
  palette="Set1" 
)
```